# Swift Error: Missing argument for parameter #1 in call

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I know there are several other posts that address this issue, however none of them seem to work for me. Am I missing something?

```
class TableViewController: UITableViewController {
    ...

    @IBAction func collegeResults(sender: AnyObject) {

    TableViewController().checkMajors() //Missing argument for parameter #1 in call
  } 



  func checkMajors(indexPath: NSIndexPath){
  ...
  }

}
```

Comment: The error message means exactly what it says. Compare the signature of the function `checkMajors` and how you call it... Apart from that, you can't initialize `TableViewController` with the default initializer `()`

Answer (score 2):

First of all, your method invocation is wrong. This line

```
TableViewController().checkMajors() //Missing argument for parameter #1 in call
```

should have invoked as

```
self.checkMajors() //Missing argument for parameter #1 in call
```

or simply

```
checkMajors() //Missing argument for parameter #1 in call
```

Now, `Missing argument for parameter #1 in call` means you didn't pass the argument the method needed. Clearly `checkMajors` takes one argument, which is a type of `NSIndexPath`. So to fix that you should invoke the method as

```
checkMajors(/* target index path */)
```

For example,

```
checkMajors(NSIndexPath(forRow:0, inSection: 0))
```